# Simple inline assembly program won't compile

Tags: c, compiler-errors, inline-assembly

This is driving me insane... I'm sure there's something very small I'm doing wrong here, but I can't figure out what it is after trying for 30 minutes and googling.  I am trying to compile a very simple C program with some inline assembly, then disassemble it, in order to get the machine code for the instructions.  This is for a school programming project.  Here is my most recent attempt:

```
int main() 
{
asm(
    "movl   $0x5bc1229f,0x0804c1e8"
    "movl   $0x08048f9c,%edx"
    "push   %edx"
    "ret"
      );
}
```

When I compile this, I get the errors:

```
/var/folders/kI/kIAe03vJFdClYy0r0mmBp++++TI/-Tmp-//cc2xKnoz.s:9:junk `movl $0x08048f9c' after expression

/var/folders/kI/kIAe03vJFdClYy0r0mmBp++++TI/-Tmp-//cc2xKnoz.s:9:bad register name `%edxpush%edxret'
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int main()
{
asm(
    "movl   $0x5bc1229f,0x0804c1e8\n\t"
    "movl   $0x08048f9c,%edx\n\t"
    "push   %edx\n\t"
    "ret\n\t"
      );
}
```

Comment: For others reading this, the  point is that anything you put in an `asm` statement is copied directly as-is into your assembly file. This means that you must manually add newline characters (`\n`) at the end of each line of assembly you write, otherwise each line will be pasted together into one long line. Tab characters (`\t`) at the end of each line are also traditional, but not necessary (they merely make the generated assembly from the compiler look nicer).

Comment: Wow thanks!  Worked perfectly.  I had read that newlines and tabs were necessary, but I wasn't putting them inside the quotes.